# Makefile loops endless

Tags: makefile, infinite-loop

My makefile loops endless but can't figure out why? Here is it further informations at sf.net/p/ags

```
    AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

    top_srcdir = $(shell pwd)/src/ags

    SUBDIRS = src/ags \
            doc

    -include ./src/ags/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/util/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/lib/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/object/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/widget/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/audio/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/audio/task/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/audio/file/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/audio/recall/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/audio/task/recall/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/file/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/X/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/X/editor/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/X/machine/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/file/Makefile.am \
            $(top_srcdir)/server/Makefile.am \
            ./doc/Makefile.am

    CC = gcc

    # what flags you want to pass to the C compiler & linker                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    CFLAGS = -g --pedantic -Wall -O -I./src -I/usr/include
    LDFLAGS = -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -lm -pthread -lrt -lgmp

    # this lists the binaries to produce, the (non-PHONY, binary) targets in                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    # the previous manual Makefile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    noinst_LIBRARIES = libags.a libags-thread.a libags-audio.a
    bin_PROGRAMS = gsequencer

    # library                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    libags_a_CFLAGS=
    libags_a_LDFLAGS =

    # application                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    gsequencer_CFLAGS=
    gsequencer_LDFLAGS=
    gsequencer_LDADD=libags.a libags-thread.a libags-audio.a

    #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    libags_audio_h_sources = $(ags_recall_audio_h_sources) $(ags_audio_task_h_sources) $(ags_xorg_task_h_sources) $(ags_audio_file_h_sources) $(ags_audio_recall_task_h_sources)
    libags_audio_c_sources = $(ags_recall_audio_c_sources) $(ags_audio_task_c_sources) $(ags_xorg_task_c_sources) $(ags_audio_file_c_sources) $(ags_audio_recall_task_c_sources)

    gsequencer_h_sources = $(ags_xorg_h_sources) $(ags_machine_h_sources) $(ags_editor_h_sources)
    gsequencer_c_sources = $(ags_xorg_c_sources) $(ags_machine_c_sources) $(ags_editor_c_sources)

    libags_a_SOURCES = $(ags_lib_c_sources) $(ags_object_c_sources) $(ags_util_c_sources)
    libags_thread_a_SOURCES = $(ags_thread_c_sources)
    libags_audio_a_SOURCES = $(ags_audio_c_sources)
    libags_gui_a_SOURCES = $(ags_widget_c_sources)

    gsequencer_SOURCES = $(gsequencer_c_sources) $(ags_server_c_sources) $(ags_file_c_sources)
```

Comment: That's not a makefile that's an automake file. And what do you mean it "loops endless". What does? Running `make`? What is it doing when it is looping? Are the timestamps on all your files accurate?

Comment: configure runs again and again

Comment: What do you mean with timestamp of all my files - there many source files. Do me have to check em all?

Comment: So `make` isn't looping at all then. `configure` is. And yes, I mean every source file and the directories. This sort of looping usually (in my experience) means that a timestamp somewhere is in the future and the autotools are noticing that and continually thinking they need to re-execute configure as a result. (Start with the autotool input files. The `.in` and `.am` files.)

Comment: You should add an automake tag to your question.  I don't remember automake supporting the `-include` directive, just `include`.  Also, I'm not sure this is how `include` is meant to be used in automake; why are you including all these `.am` files here?  I would think that these directories would be added as SUBDIRS.

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry for late response, but I'm encountering the same issue. `configure` finishes but `make` starts calling `configure` again infinitely. So running `make` *is* actually what's causing it.

Comment: @notbad.jpeg No, that's still likely the autotools doing it (they inject commands into the running of make to detect clock skew, staleness, etc. and re-run configure ... or did last time I looked). Check your timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Wiping all build scripts

```
rm *
```

Touching all files

```
find . -type f | xargs touch
```

Running the following to rebuild build scripts did it finally

```
aclocal
autoheader
libtoolize --force --copy
automake --add-missing --copy --foreign
autoconf
./configure
make
```

PROBLEM: empty Makefile.am caused infinite loop
SOLUTION: add an empty variable to it